# Unable to make a backward TAB as Shift-TAB in Zsh

Tags: tabs, zsh

**Problem:** to navigate backwards with TAB in Zsh similarly as in Firefox by

```
Shift-TAB
```

**Example of what Shift-TAB should do**

I run the following code in terminal

```
ls <TAB>
```

I get

```
A B C D E F G H I J K H L M N...
```

I see the following in Zsh as I press TAB
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/smallEx.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/smallEx.png)

I navigate to the folder J by TAB. Then, I observe that I pressed once too often the tab key.

**How can you make a backward TAB for Zsh** similar as Firefox's Shift-TAB?

Comment: Old question... today is possible to achieve [a bindkey more portable](https://code.google.com/p/vinipsmaker/source/diff?spec=svn9d8ecf0dc85db1e577ffea8684db53a846bb830c&r=9d8ecf0dc85db1e577ffea8684db53a846bb830c&format=side&path=/config/.zshrc)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try this:

```
bindkey '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
```

If this doesn't work, try running executing zsh like this (which does `setopt MENU_COMPLETE`):

```
zsh -Y
```

and then try again!

Comment: Where do you find the key command `'^[[Z'` it's not too intuitive for my little 

Comment: @martisj: "^[[Z" (read: escape, left bracket, capital z) is the sequence that most terminals write onto the shell's standard input for shift-tab. Just copy paste the above into zsh or some startup rc file and shift-tab should work. If it doesn't, try it with different terminals too, maybe it's a problem with your terminal.

Comment: Thank you @ypsu, do you of a reference for these sequences?

Comment: @martisj: It's a per terminal setting. Looking through the "infocmp" command's output for my terminal it looks like this is the "cbt" or "kcbt" capability. According to "man terminfo" this means "back_tab". You can find the rest of the sequences and their explanation through these two sources. If you are only curious what a given key generates, just run "stty raw ; cat" and press the key you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

This document should give you a good explanation:

- [Q: How do i get Shift-Tab to go backwards on a text terminal or XTerm?](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/daveg/Info/backtab-howto.txt)

In short, few terminals support a shifted Tab, but you might be able to get your terminal to support a "backtab" key sequence which you can configure X to send.

Comment: This is awkward. A good (and non-clean, as opposed to your suggestion) would be to make .zshrc support several querying (terminfo, zkbd, manual) backends and make your zsh work under SSH, xterm, linux console, linux raw console and whatever... but this suggestion needs to patch so many components of the OS and it will lead to non-functional zsh configuration under other systems... so awkard

Comment: This is ONLY a historical reason, and this old default should be changed in zsh, which is not usually deployed in legacy systems.

As evidenced in the massive upvotes of the ACTUAL solution, people's terminals DO work with shift+tab

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you require by a backward-tab, but zsh *does* have an undo zle widget which undoes the effect of the last pressed keystroke, be it Tab or anything else. Use it by binding it to a key:

```
$> bindkey "<Ctrl-V><Shift-Tab>" undo
```

The  means you press those key combos, don't type out the letters.

I think this is what you're asking for, but I can't tell for sure without more examples.

Comment: I added a picture to my Question. I shows what I am trying to achieve. I backTAB, for instance, for the command cd.

Comment: @sykora: It does not. It ignores the TAB completion, and undo the "d" in the command cd.

Comment: @sykora: I get the following code: bindkey ^[[Z undo. I put it to terminal and it gives me zsh: bad pattern: ^[[Z.

Comment: Gah, forgot the quotes. Now try it.

Comment: @sykora: Do you use Ctrl-V always when you try to make these keybindings. It seems to be like xev which shows what you type, but it is builtin feature in Shell.

Comment: Use the bindkey command. Ctrl-V is bound to quoted insert. That means that anything typed after Ctrl-V is inserted as-is, and no effect is carried out. This way you can insert control-sequences literally.